# How to reduce space between table and paragraph in HTML?

Tags: html-table, space, paragraph

I am using HTML table followed by paragraph but I found space between the table and paragraph is more than needed. How can I control (reduce) the space between table and paragraph.

```
<table border=1><tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr></table>
<p style="width: 100%; text-align: right;"><button type="button" id="submit-button" style='visibility:hidden;width:1px;height:1px' >Submit</button></p>
```

Comment: Use `margin-top: 0;` for your `<p>`.

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://www.drupal.org/node/46808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Margin-top:0%**

```
<table border=1><tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr></table>
<p style=" margin-top:0%;width: 100%; text-align: right;"><button type="button" id="submit-button" style='visibility:hidden;width:1px;height:1px' >Submit</button></p>
```